# Reviving MySQL installation

Tags: mysql

I am sharing a server with a group. Until recently everything was savvy and worked seamlessly.
On Tuesday afternoon someone uninstalled MySQL.

Since this server was setup 5 years ago I don't remember which version of MySQL I had. 5.0 or 5.1. Can I determine this from the data files somehow?

Second question is how do I get my hands on a Msi for 5.0. I've tried playing around with 5.1 and it seems to have conflicts with the data files.

I have a back up of the data files to play around with.

Comment: Is this a programming question or a sysadmin question?

Comment: My guess is that it's a programming question.

I'm wondering if there is a way to identify which version of mysql created a datafile.

Answer (score 3):

I've solved this problem.

1. I uninstalled MySQL
2. Deleted the generic dataFile Folders that the Installation had created. (I had a backup of my old datafiles)
3. Deleted the MySQL Install Folder (in Program Files)
4. Went through the registry and deleted a lot of the the MySQL entries. (Backed it up first, of course)
5. Installed MySQL 5.1, and changed the datafile locations to something new D:\myDataFiles
6. Started the server (Didn't receive any errors)
7. Shutdown the server and dropped in one of my datafiles (from backup)
8. Restarted the server and was able to access that DB
9. Did this a few times for each dataFile that I had

I can't tell you what fixed it, but I'm glad it's working. Hopefully this will help out someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.0.html

Note: This is a Community MySQL Server

Comment: Before I do that is there any way of determining what version of MySQL created the datafiles?

I have tried that already, and it might be a stupid question, but it's a zip archive, and I don't see a setup file. The server is running Windows Server 2003.